# How to stop an object from moving while changing its shape?

Tags: modeling

I have a UV sphere that I want to compress into an oblong shape. So, I will start compressing it at the UV sphere's top vertex, the bullseye looking vertex.  In tutorials, you press  <kbd>G</kbd> to transform or change its shape. Mine only moves the object while grabbing it and doesn't change shape.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I tried compressing it by pressing  <kbd>G</kbd> at the top vertex. Instead, it passes through my table model, sinking and phasing through rather than being compressed.

I only started today and have about 10 hours spent.

Comment: Hello ! You most likely have proportional editing on. Look for this icon and click on it to disable it https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RBtN.png

Comment: or press O to enable it

Comment: Thank you! It's now stationary.